# Change appearance of view used by DragShadowBuilder

Tags: android, android-layout, drag-and-drop, android-support-library

I want to implement a drag-and-drop functionality within a recyclerview. Everything goes perfectly until I want to customize the looks of the view being dragged (not the view from which the drag event starts, I want to modify the "shadow" and keep the original view the same).

I've tried to make a bitmap out of the view being passed, but the end result is both the original item and the Shadow are modified AND the original view loses its position on the list... WTF

Here is my code:

```
public class ImageDragShadowBuilder extends View.DragShadowBuilder {
    private Bitmap shadow;

    LinearLayout linearLayout;

    private ImageDragShadowBuilder() {
        super();
    }

    public static ImageDragShadowBuilder create(Context context, View view) {
        ImageDragShadowBuilder builder = new ImageDragShadowBuilder();
        builder.linearLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.metric_item);
        builder.linearLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_item_dragging);

        builder.shadow = createBitmapFromView(builder.linearLayout);

        return builder;
    }

    public View getLayout() {
        return linearLayout;
    }

    private static Bitmap createBitmapFromView(View v) {
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getWidth(), v.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        v.layout(0, 0, v.getWidth(), v.getHeight());
        v.draw(new Canvas(b));
        return b;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawShadow(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(shadow, 0, 0, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProvideShadowMetrics(Point shadowSize, Point shadowTouchPoint) {
        shadowSize.x = shadow.getWidth();
        shadowSize.y = shadow.getHeight();
        shadowTouchPoint.x = shadowSize.x / 2;
        shadowTouchPoint.y = shadowSize.y / 2;
    }
}
```

**Any ideas?**

Answer (score 1):

I think that there are 2 problems :

- Setting the background on the view attached to the RecyclerView affects the original item and the shadow
- Triggering a layout changes the item's children position

Basically you can use the original view, but you should never modify it. A slightly modified version of your shadow builder could be :

```
public static ImageDragShadowBuilder create(Context context, View view) {
    ImageDragShadowBuilder builder = new ImageDragShadowBuilder();
    builder.linearLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.metric_item);

    // do not change the original view
    // we will draw the background directly later
    // builder.linearLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_item_dragging);

    builder.shadow = createBitmapFromView(builder.linearLayout);

    return builder;
}

private static Bitmap createBitmapFromView(View v) {
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getWidth(), v.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    // do not change the original view
    // v.layout(0, 0, v.getWidth(), v.getHeight());

    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);

    // draw the background
    Drawable background = v.getContext().getDrawable(R.drawable.background_item_dragging);
    background.setBounds(0, 0, b.getWidth(), b.getHeight());
    background.draw(c);

    v.draw(c);
    return b;
}
```

Comment: `v.getContext().getDrawable()` can only be used from *21* and I'm limited to *16* is there any alternative? I've tried `ContextCompat.getDrawable(v.getContext()`, ID) but this won't change the background. That being said the original item no longer moves away so that's a good start!

Comment: MORE INFO. I suspected I was due to something else and it appears to be because the original view already has a background! **It's doesn't have to do with the way I get the Drawable (whether is 21 or 16)** SO next question is... could it be possible to apply the effect and keep the background??

Comment: `Context.getDrawable()` is just a shortcut for `Context.getResources().getDrawable(...)`

Comment: I think the point is : you can you what you want in the Bitmap, draw the View, a Drawable, or something else, as long as you do not change the View : you don't own it, it is still attached in the RecyclerView